# When using mode: no-cors for a request, browser isn’t adding request header I’ve set in my frontend code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch-api

in my React app, I have the following API POST to allow the user to edit their profile (name and image).

```
  static updateProfile(formData, user_id) {
    const request = new Request(`http://localhost:4300/api/v1/profiles/${user_id}`, {
      headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': getBearerToken()
      }),
      mode: 'no-cors',
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    });

    return fetch(request).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).catch(error => {
      return error;
    });
  }
```

The problem with the above is the header with the Authorization token is not being sent in the POST...

How can I get the Authorization header to be send in the fetch request above?

FYI, for non-multipart forms, the authorization token is sent successfully like so:

```
  static loadProfile(user_id) {
    const request = new Request(`http://localhost:4300/api/v1/profiles/${user_id}`, {
      headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': getBearerToken(),
        'Accept'       : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      })
    });

    return fetch(request).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).catch(error => {
      return error;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can’t use `no-cors` mode if you set any special request headers, because one effect of using it is: it tells browsers to not allow your frontend JavaScript code to set any request headers other than [CORS-safelisted request-headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header). See [the spec requirements](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-headers-append):

> To append a *name*/*value* pair to a `Headers` object (*headers*), run these steps:
>
> 5. Otherwise, if *guard* is "`request-no-cors`" and *name*/*value* is not a [CORS-safelisted request-header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header), return.

In that algorithm, `return` equates to “return without adding that header to the Headers object”.

`Authorization` isn’t a [CORS-safelisted request-header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header), so your browser won’t allow you to set if you use `no-cors` mode for a request. Same for `Content-Type: application/json`.

If the reason you’re trying to use `no-cors` mode is to avoid some other problem that occurs if you don’t use, the solution is to fix the underlying cause of that other problem. Because no matter what problem you might be trying to solve, `no-cors` mode isn’t going to turn out to be a solution in the end. It’s just going to create different problems like what you’re hitting.

Comment: Can I turn re enable cors and then send the header along w multipart form data?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to just remove `mode: 'no-cors'` and make the request. If when you do that you get some different error message, then you probably want to update your question to include whatever other error message you get without `mode: 'no-cors'`, and then we could try to find a solution to that problem.

Answer (score -1):

By using below code you can make a fetch request with Authorization or bearer

```
    var url = "https://yourUrl";
    var bearer = 'Bearer '+ bearer_token;
    fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    withCredentials: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': bearer,
        'X-FP-API-KEY': 'iphone',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then((responseJson) => {
        var items = JSON.parse(responseJson._bodyInit);
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({
    isLoading: false,
    message: 'Something bad happened ' + error
    }));
```