# Setting authorization header in Fetch API

Tags: reactjs, express, fetch-api

I have a Node/Express backend and I'm consuming the API with a React Client. I want to be able to set the authorization header after a user is signed up. This ensures that subsequent requests are sent with the authorization header.

I can see how it's done in Axios [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014034/setting-authorization-header-in-axios) and how to retrieve the authorization header in Fetch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747874/with-a-fetch-api-sending-typemultipart-form-data-how-to-send-an-authorization)

Is it possible to do this with Fetch API and how?

Comment: same issue I'm facing please let me know if you got the solution @Rowland

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to use default options/headers with `fetch`. You can use [this third party library](https://github.com/moll/js-fetch-defaults) to get it to work, or set up some default options that you then use with every request:

```js
// defaultOptions.js
const defaultOptions = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': getTokenFromStore(),
  },
};

export default defaultOptions;
```

Then use the default options like:

```js
import defaultOptions from './defaultOptions';

// With default options:
fetch('/auth', defaultOptions);

// With additional (non-default) options:
fetch('/auth', { ...defaultOptions, body: JSON.stringify(additionalData) });
```

Comment: Thank you. I use all of that but I think there should be a way to set authorization header with Fetch API. The issue is not making a request with it but setting it after authenticating the user such that in my **network** panel in the dev tool, for instance, I can see it set like other things.

Answer (score 90):

```
var url = "https://yourUrl";
var bearer = 'Bearer ' + bearer_token;
fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': bearer,
            'X-FP-API-KEY': 'iphone', //it can be iPhone or your any other attribute
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(responseJson => {
        var items = JSON.parse(responseJson._bodyInit);
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        message: 'Something bad happened ' + error
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks! It was the "withCredentials"/"credentials" properties that did the trick for me.  Without them, my Authorization header was not being sent.

Comment: how to get bearer_token when it need to await?

Comment: @famfamfam Use `await` in front of the call that fetches the bearer token, same as any other async call you want the resolved value for.

Comment: Good answer, but `JSON.parse(responseJson._bodyInit);` is a bit odd. I'd use the public JSON body parsing API: `fetch().then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data))` (error handling left as an exercise).

Comment: thanks you @ggorlen, my question created when i learning React Native, know i got it bro!

Answer (score 6):

You can pass headers as second parameter of fetch:

```
fetch(<your url>, {
  headers: {
     authorization: <whatever is needed here>
   }
})
```

Comment: want to pass all the values such as :                                                          
Consumer Key: value

Consumer Secret: value

Access Token: value

Access Token Secret: value

Comment: you can add those as keys to `headers` object: `{ authorization: <whatever is needed here>, 'consumer key': <value>, 'consumer secret': <value>, 'Access Token': <value>, 'Access token secret': <value> } `

Comment: This does not work. It throw error: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status"

Comment: This is too vague to need to be helpful. There are [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48943220/6243352) that supersede this and show how to actually build the request, with correct syntax, leaving nothing to guesswork.

Answer (score 5):

```
   headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;
  },
```

Comment: What does this add to the existing answers, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48943220/6243352), which shows the whole fetch call? `localStorage` is irrelevant except for your particular case. Programmers will know how to adapt whatever means of retrieval they're using for the token, where it's a variable, env var, database, `localStorage`, HTTP endpoint... there's no need to add an answer for each of these sources.