# Fetching from API in React with key in headers, returning 406 not acceptable

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch from an API, using an API key, but keep getting 406 Not Acceptable.
I can get the request to work in Postman, but not in the code. What could be wrong here? I've tried all sorts of ways of including my info in headers, this is just my last attempt.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("my-api", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: ({
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Api-Version": 20161108,
      Authorization: {
          Token: "my-api-key",
      }
     }),
      body: JSON.stringify()
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.status === 201) {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json()
      } else {
        console.log("oh no!", response.status === 404)
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: check this, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406. Maybe the content that you are trying to work with isn't quite accepted in the same format as you would expect by the server

Comment: Try adding `credentials: 'include'`. Without that, the browser doesn’t actually add the Authorization header to the request it sends. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included

Comment: I have added `Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",`  and `credentials: include`, but still not working. The api is based on http://jsonapi.org/ so I don't get why this seems so complicated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting authorization header in Fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535913/setting-authorization-header-in-fetch-api)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. This ended up working:

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch("my api", {
          method: "GET",
          headers: ({
          Accept: "application/vnd.api+json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-Api-Version": 20161108,
          Authorization: "Token my token",
         }),
          body: JSON.stringify()
        }).then(response => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log(response)
            return response.json()
          } else {
            console.log("oh no!", response.status === 404)
          }
        })
      }
```