# Discord api get guild

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to fetch my guild info from discord API

```
fetch('https://discord.com/api/guilds/772037458996101140', {
            headers: {
                authorization: 'bot Nzc******zNjYzOTAz.GPwhCV.rhIcH****5R8ZS-cIo4MjPcBVxO6wYsUXhY'
            },
        })
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(console.error)
```

Only receiving 401 (unauthorized)

I tried changing "bot" to "BOT", "Bot", "Bearer"
and doing authorization using access token from Oauth2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was sending http request from **front-end** and when i moved it to **back-end** or just used python test file it worked using : `Authorization: 'Bot <TOKEN>'`

*not sure why but it works how it should mby somebody can explain ?*

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in how the Authorization header has been specified. The correct way specify `headers` would be:

```js
fetch('https://discord.com/api/guilds/772037458996101140', {
            withCredentials: true,
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
            'Authorization': 'bot Nzc******zNjYzOTAz.GPwhCV.rhIcH****5R8ZS-cIo4MjPcBVxO6wYsUXhY',
            },
        })
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(console.error)
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

Also added [`crendentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials#examples) and [`withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535913/setting-authorization-header-in-fetch-api).

Comment: Your answer is wrong, because the second argument of `fetch` is for options, not headers.

Comment: thank you for responding, but nothing changed... i forgot to mention that i use the same authorization method for another discord API requests (with "beaver" not "bot" authorization) and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you were having getting the 401 response but I do see one issue, the url you are sending a request to doesn't specify what API version to use.

The url would be `https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/772037458996101140`

And maybe consider using the discord api exclusively on the backend if you are making your site public, because it leaves your token in your source code for anyone to yoink